# rewrite animation to be time based (not flat speed based)

Tags: javascript, animation, math, time

For some time now i am using animation for bullets, animation makes bullets go in sinusoidal trajectory from start point to end point. The only problem with animation i am having is that it is using flat `speed` param for to move and i wanted to convert this so it uses time instead. This way you could actually say that bullet will go for 2 seconds, otherwise you wont know when it arrives.

After some study i figured that bullet needs these:

- time (how much time travel should take, for example 2 seconds)
- elapsed (how much time have passed since it started)
- started (when travel has started)

these will allow you to calculate how much time passed since bullet was fired and based on how much time it was suppose to be travelling you can know where it should be in particular time point (for example after 1.2 seconds)

Since the script makes bullet to travel in sinusoidal manner i have no clue how to implement it though.

The script:

```js
var cvs = document.querySelector('canvas'),
    ctx = cvs.getContext('2d'),
    w, h, cx, cy,
    resize = function() {
        w = cvs.width = window.innerWidth;
        cx = w / 2;
        h = cvs.height = window.innerHeight;
        cy = h / 2;
    },
    tools = {
        rnd: (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (Math.floor(max) - Math.ceil(min) + 1)) + Math.ceil(min),
        flt: (min, max, dec) => parseFloat((Math.random() * (min - max) + max).toFixed(dec)),
        distance: (p1, p2) => Math.sqrt((p1.x - p2.x) * (p1.x - p2.x) + (p1.y - p2.y) * (p1.y - p2.y)),
        rftv: (p1, p2) => Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x)
    },
    loop = function() {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

        for (var i = pool.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // move bullet
            pool[i].move();

            // bullet
            ctx.save();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(pool[i].x, pool[i].y, pool[i].r, Math.PI * 2, 0);
            ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(100, 100%, 50%)';
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.restore();

            // start location
            ctx.save();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(pool[i].ix, pool[i].iy, pool[i].r, Math.PI * 2, 0);
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsl(100, 100%, 50%)';
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.restore();

            // end location
            ctx.save();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(pool[i].dx, pool[i].dy, pool[i].r, Math.PI * 2, 0);
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsl(100, 100%, 50%)';
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.restore();

            // remove bullet when it arrives
            if (pool[i].remaining <= 0) {
                pool.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    },
    pool = [],
    last_spawn = 0,
    spawn_interval = 0,
    spawn_limit = 1,
    spawn = function() {
        if (Date.now() - last_spawn > spawn_interval) {
            last_spawn = Date.now();
            for (var i = 0; i < spawn_limit; i++) {
                pool.push(new particle());
            }
        }
    },
    particle = function() {
        var exvec = tools.rnd(20, w - 20),
            eyvec = tools.rnd(20, h - 20),
            svecs = {
                x: cx,
                y: cy
            },
            evecs = {
                x: exvec,
                y: eyvec
            },
            rad = tools.rftv(svecs, evecs),
            distance = tools.distance(svecs, evecs);
        this.time = 2 * 1000; // time in seconds for example 2 seconds === 2 * 1000 = 2000 ms
        this.elapsed = 0; // how much time passed since it started
        this.started = Date.now(); // time of departure

        this.ix = cx; // start x axis
        this.iy = cy; // start y axis
        this.dx = exvec; // end x axis
        this.dy = eyvec; // end y axis
        this.x = cx; // current x axis
        this.y = cy; // current y axis
        this.r = 10; // radius of bullet
        this.rad = rad; // needed for computation
        this.period = distance / 2; // how many axis changes
        this.distance = 0; // how much distance bullet travelled
        this.total = distance; // how much distance there is in total to be made
        this.remaining = distance; // difference between total and made
        this.amplitude = distance / 2; // how big hump
        this.speed = 2; // flat speed increase
        this.move = function() { // this is function for to calculate move
            this.elapsed = Date.now() - this.started;
            this.distance += this.speed;
            this.remaining = this.total - this.distance;

            this.x = this.ix + Math.cos(this.rad) * this.distance;
            this.y = this.iy + Math.sin(this.rad) * this.distance;

            const deviation = Math.sin(this.distance * Math.PI / this.period) * this.amplitude;

            this.x += Math.sin(this.rad) * deviation;
            this.y -= Math.cos(this.rad) * deviation;
        };
    };

resize();
loop();

window.onresize = function() {
    resize();
};

spawn();
```

```css
body {
 overflow:hidden;
}

canvas {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

The most important stuff is inside `this.move` function as it does entire moving, i have already implemented calculation of time (hoping its correct) but i dont know how to modify current movement code so it is affected by time and not by `speed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIU your question, your animation is based on `requestAnimationFrame` which is not guaranteed to be schedule over fixed intervals so logic that uses fixed speed

```
        this.distance += this.speed;
```

doesn't really work for you and you want to calculate `this.distance` based on the actual elapsed time

```
        this.elapsed = Date.now() - this.started
```

If this is so, the change is trivial: for any given moment current distance should be the same part of the whole distance as current elapsed time is a part of the whole time. So in terms of your code:

```
        this.distance = distance * this.elapsed / this.time;
```

Or to update your demo:

```js
var cvs = document.querySelector('canvas'),
    ctx = cvs.getContext('2d'),
    w, h, cx, cy,
    resize = function () {
        w = cvs.width = window.innerWidth;
        cx = w / 2;
        h = cvs.height = window.innerHeight;
        cy = h / 2;
    },
    tools = {
        rnd: (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (Math.floor(max) - Math.ceil(min) + 1)) + Math.ceil(min),
        flt: (min, max, dec) => parseFloat((Math.random() * (min - max) + max).toFixed(dec)),
        distance: (p1, p2) => Math.sqrt((p1.x - p2.x) * (p1.x - p2.x) + (p1.y - p2.y) * (p1.y - p2.y)),
        rftv: (p1, p2) => Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x)
    },
    globalStart = Date.now(),
    loop = function () {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

        var globalElapsed = Date.now() - globalStart;
        ctx.font = '48px serif';
        ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(50, 100%, 50%)';
        var text = (pool.length > 0) ? globalElapsed / 1000 : "End";
        ctx.fillText(text, 40, 50);

        for (var i = pool.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            // move bullet
            pool[i].move();

            // bullet
            ctx.save();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(pool[i].x, pool[i].y, pool[i].r, Math.PI * 2, 0);
            ctx.fillStyle = 'hsl(100, 100%, 50%)';
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.restore();

            // start location
            ctx.save();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(pool[i].ix, pool[i].iy, pool[i].r, Math.PI * 2, 0);
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsl(100, 100%, 50%)';
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.restore();

            // end location
            ctx.save();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(pool[i].dx, pool[i].dy, pool[i].r, Math.PI * 2, 0);
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsl(100, 100%, 50%)';
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.restore();

            // remove bullet when it arrives
            if (pool[i].remaining <= 0) {
                pool.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    },
    pool = [],
    last_spawn = 0,
    spawn_interval = 0,
    spawn_limit = 1,
    spawn = function () {
        if (Date.now() - last_spawn > spawn_interval) {
            last_spawn = Date.now();
            for (var i = 0; i < spawn_limit; i++) {
                pool.push(new particle());
            }
        }
    },
    particle = function () {
        var exvec = tools.rnd(20, w - 20),
            eyvec = tools.rnd(20, h - 20),
            svecs = {
                x: cx,
                y: cy
            },
            evecs = {
                x: exvec,
                y: eyvec
            },
            rad = tools.rftv(svecs, evecs),
            distance = tools.distance(svecs, evecs);
        this.time = 10 * 1000; // time in seconds for example 2 seconds === 2 * 1000 = 2000 ms
        this.elapsed = 0; // how much time passed since it started
        this.started = Date.now(); // time of departure

        this.ix = cx; // start x axis
        this.iy = cy; // start y axis
        this.dx = exvec; // end x axis
        this.dy = eyvec; // end y axis
        this.x = cx; // current x axis
        this.y = cy; // current y axis
        this.r = 10; // radius of bullet
        this.rad = rad; // needed for computation
        this.period = distance / 2; // how many axis changes
        this.distance = 0; // how much distance bullet travelled
        this.total = distance; // how much distance there is in total to be made
        this.remaining = distance; // difference between total and made
        this.amplitude = distance / 4; // how big hump
        // this.speed = 2; // flat speed increase
        this.move = function () { // this is function for to calculate move
            this.elapsed = Date.now() - this.started;
            // this.distance += this.speed;
            this.distance = distance * this.elapsed / this.time;
            this.remaining = this.total - this.distance;

            this.x = this.ix + Math.cos(this.rad) * this.distance;
            this.y = this.iy + Math.sin(this.rad) * this.distance;

            const deviation = Math.sin(this.distance * Math.PI / this.period) * this.amplitude;

            this.x += Math.sin(this.rad) * deviation;
            this.y -= Math.cos(this.rad) * deviation;
        };
    };

resize();
loop();

window.onresize = function () {
    resize();
};

spawn();
```

```css
body {
 overflow:hidden;
}

canvas {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Note that

1. I changed `this.time` to 10 seconds to seconds so animation is easier to track
2. I added `globalStart` and `globalElapsed` to draw actual time inside `loop`
3. I reduced the size of the curve to better fit smaller area here

Comment: requestAnimationFrame passes an HighResDOMTimestamp to the callback. Use it instead of new Date

Comment: @Kaiido, this is generally a good idea but 1. I didn't want to make the example over-complicated. 2. Depending on the list of target browsers the value passed into the callback might actually come from different sources. In [modern browsers](https://www.w3.org/TR/animation-timing/#Window-interface-extensions) it should be HighResDOMTimestamp  but in older it might still be Date.now() or even worse.

Comment: for 1 I don't think it needs to be complicated to just let know some time info is available, and for 2, every native implementations and correct polyfill will pass an HighResDOMTimestamp or a polyfill of it (i.e based on page opening time).

Comment: about that HighResDOMTimestamp, doesnt it deliver value from 0 forward since the moment animation started instead of real time? how to incorporate it into this kind of logic (instead of `Date.now()` make use of timestamp from rAF)?

Comment: @Mevia, unless your animation is really short time, I think the simplest and the most reliable method is to use the time passed at the very first call to the callback to init `startTime`. Something like the code in the answer to the linked (duplicate) question looks reasonable, although you'll have to store `startTime` as a property of the object instead of global `var`.